# Do I need to put a license in my website's HTML and/or CSS?

Tags: javascript, licensing, web-development, html, css

I am making a website for a competition my school is taking part in, however I am not on the team and am not receiving any compensation (save for better references :P). The only condition I have set is that I receive full credit and attributions.

All of my Javascript files have MIT licenses at the top, as they were written as libraries some time ago, and I want to ensure that my conditions are met. I also want to put a license in my HTML and CSS, but I have never seen anyone do that before.

Is there any reason not to put a license in my HTML and CSS files, but to put one in my Javascript? What type of license can I use?

Answer (score 2):

You can add whatever license you want to your CSS files.  Here's an [example](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css).

One way to receive credit and attributions is putting "Designed by xxx" in the footer of the site (make sure the team or the school is aware).

Answer (score -3):

No, CSS and HTML files don't really need their own licensing.

Nothing is stopping you from finding something and putting it in there though, *anything* can be licensed.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.

Comment: That statement is incorrect. Please prove me wrong.

Comment: It depends what he wants to achieve with the license. If he wants to stop people using his code without his permission, then he does not need a license to do that, all code is implicitly copyrighted by its author and if no license is given it does not mean people can do what they like with it. On the other hand, if he wants to guarantee it can be used by anyone, then he may want to put a permissive license on it.